# How to create a JSF (XHTML) facelets page in IBM Rational Application Developer for Websphere 8.5

Tags: jsf, ide, facelets, ibm-rad, ibm-rational

I have just installed IBM RAD 8.5 for Webpshere and on the contrary to what IBM advertises as JSF 2 Tools support featuring a rich editor comes with RAD 8.5, I could not even find the option of creating an xhtml page from File > New - despite also the fact that I had even added JSF 2.0 to the project facets.

Anyone knows how to activate facelets (xhtml) creation for JSF development in RAD 8.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a web JSF2.0 project, you should create New->Web Page and you will get xhtml format selected by default.

[image: new web page]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

File ==> New ==> Webpages ==> Select HTML
Here while entering file name enter myfile.xhtml
finish the process.